# R package: use %>% symbol when dplyr package is loaded as Imports

Tags: r, dplyr, syntax, dependencies, r-package

I am working on my R package following this [great guide](https://tinyheero.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/07/26/making-your-first-R-package.html) and I would like to use [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) loading it as `Imports` in my package. In `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
...
Imports:
  dplyr (>= 1.1.3),
Depends:
    R (>= 2.10)
...
```

The problem is that if I load it as `Imports` as in the example above I got this error when I use `%>%` in my functions:

> could not find function "%>%"

I know that if I load `dplyr` as `Depends` in `DESCRIPTION` file I can use the symbol whit no further specification, but I would like to work it around keeping `dplyr` as `Imports`

Comment: Do you list `dplyr` (and/or `%>%` specifically) in your `NAMESPACE` file? The two must work together, having it in just one does not satisfy all requirements.

Comment: `usethis::use_pipe()`, which will be available to you if you're using the `devtools` package (I recommend that you do) will take care of the set up for you.  Just type it at the command prompt with your package open and you should be able to use `%>%` in your package without any problems after that.  See [here](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_pipe.html).

Comment: The  pipe operator `%>%` is actually in the "magrittr" library/package and not in dplyr.

Comment: @BenBolker.  Thanks, but I don't think it's an answer in itself, more a comment on your answer.  You provided the theory, I simply imentioned a simple implementation.  Feel free edit your answer to include it if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Imports` alone does not specify *which* functions should be imported. Since you're using roxygen (according to the guide), you should add `#' @importFrom dplyr %>%` somewhere in your code (then run `devtools::document()` appropriately). (`%>%` is actually defined in the `magrittr` package, but it is imported and re-exported from `dplyr` ...) You'll need to do this for *all* `dplyr` functions that you use, unless you preface them with `dplyr::` (e.g. `dplyr::filter()`). (In contrast to most functions, `dplyr::%>%` doesn't work, which is the reason you *must* explicitly use `importFrom` ...)

@Limey points out in comments that running `usethis::use_pipe()` will automatically add this information to your package.

This confusion is specifically addressed in [this section](https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-in-practice.html#confusion-about-imports) of Wickham's *R Packages* book; see also [here](https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-in-practice.html#sec-dependencies-NAMESPACE-workflow) (it's a little surprising that the blog author didn't mention this ...)

If you want to go old-school, add `importFrom(dplyr, %>%)` in your `NAMESPACE` file instead of adding roxygen `@importFrom` specifications.

If you want to import *all* of the `dplyr` functions, you can follow Wickham's advice here (including why *not* to do it this way):

> Sometimes you make such heavy use of so many functions from another package that you want to import its entire namespace. This should be relatively rare. ... [specifies using `#' @import pkgname` ...]  This is the least recommended solution because it can make your code harder to read (you can’t tell where a function is coming from), and if you `@import` many packages, it increases the chance of function name conflicts. Save this for very special situations.

Comment: For the reason of confusion (source of functions), I often do `@import otherpkg` and then still do `otherpkg::somefunc`. It seems redundant but completely legal. I agree with the sloppiness of importing a whole other package, it would be nice to have some of python's import mechanisms in base R.

Comment: It's yet another package, but I think the [box package](https://github.com/klmr/box) might give you some of this flexibility (full disclosure, I haven't really investigated it)

Comment: I've seen `box` and it has some appeal.